# Find the rate of change of f with respect to t along the curve.

Tags: calculus

$f (x, y) = x^2 y,$

$r (t) = e^t i + e^{(-t)}j$

So what I did first in this problem was do the partial derivative for f(x,y)

$\frac{df}{dx}$ = $2xy$

$\frac{df}{dy}$ = $ x^2$

$ ▽f$ = $2xyi + x^2j$

Then I did  $▽f(rt) * r'(t)$ = $e^ti+e^{(-t)}j * e^ti  -e^{(-t)}j$

Regrettably I did not get the right answer. Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x,y)=x^2y$, $x(t)=e^t$, and $y(t)=e^{-t}$, then $f(x(t),y(t))=e^{2t}e^{-t}=e^t$ So, $\frac{df}{dt}=e^t$.

Using the chain rule $\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}$ yields the same answer.

Comment: What I am confused about is how does one compute $▽f(r(t))$?

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}=2xy(e^t)+x^2(-e^{-t})=2e^t(e^{-t})(e^t)+e^{2t}(-e^{-t})=e^t$, where $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are the component functions $r(t)=x(t)\hat{i}+y(t)\hat{j}$.